# initialize a vector by a pointer of a CLASS

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to initialize a vector of pointers of a class UNITCallback.
Here is the code:
file vector.h

```
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>

class UNITEvent_Loop;

class UNITCallback
{
public:
            UNITCallback();
   virtual ~UNITCallback();
   virtual const fd_set &   FdSet() = 0;
   virtual void             operator()(const fd_set & fds) = 0;
   virtual void             operator()() = 0;
   virtual void             eventLoop(UNITEvent_Loop * ev);
   virtual UNITEvent_Loop * eventLoop();

private:
   UNITEvent_Loop * evt_loop_;
};



class UNITEvent_Loop
{
public:
   enum priority { LOW , HIGH};
   UNITEvent_Loop();
  ~UNITEvent_Loop();

   void stopLoop();
   void runLoop();
   void runLoop(int timeout); // in milliseconds
   void runLoop(struct timeval * TO);

private:

   UNITEvent_Loop & operator =(const UNITEvent_Loop &);
   UNITEvent_Loop(const UNITEvent_Loop &);
   std::auto_ptr<struct CMSPEvent_LoopImpl> impl_;
};
```

file vector.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include"vector.h"


struct UNITEvent_LoopImpl
    {
    UNITEvent_LoopImpl() :
        stopLoop(false),
        callBacks(1024,0),//(FD_SETSIZE, 0),
        priorities(FD_SETSIZE, UNITEvent_Loop::LOW) {};

      //CMSPMutex protect;
      bool      stopLoop;
      std::vector<UNITCallback * > callBacks;
      std::vector<UNITEvent_Loop::priority> priorities;
    };

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

so when I compile I receive:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of ‘void
std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_Integer, _Integer,
std::__true_type) [with _Integer = int; _Tp = UNITCallback*; _Alloc =
std::allocator<UNITCallback*>]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:555:4:   required from
‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator,
const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = int; _Tp =
UNITCallback*; _Alloc = std::allocator<UNITCallback*>;
std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type =
std::allocator<UNITCallback*>]’
/vector/src/vector.cpp:20:48:   required
from here /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:1426:52: error: invalid
conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector<UNITCallback*>::value_type’ {aka
‘UNITCallback*’} [-fpermissive]
    _M_fill_initialize(static_cast<size_type>(__n), __value);
                                                    ^~~~~~~
```

it looks like I can't initialize well. why?
EDIT:
I will add the cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.4)

cmake_policy (VERSION 3.11.4)

project (MSG_IMPF CXX C Fortran)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -fpic -shared")
#at moment missing -lnsl -lsocket
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lrt -lpthread")

#Appending to corresponding CMake variables:

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")

add_definitions(-D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -D__EXTENSIONS__  -DIT_USE_STD_IOSTREAM)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH ON)
get_filename_component(LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} PATH)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LOCATION}/lib64)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LOCATION}/lib64)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LOCATION}/bin)


include_directories(
    ${LOCATION}/src
)

add_executable(test1
vector.cpp
)
```

so the verbose is:
/usr/bin/c++  -DIT_USE_STD_IOSTREAM -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -D__EXTENSIONS__ -I/vector/src  -g -fpic -shared   -std=gnu++98 -o CMakeFiles/test1.dir/vector.cpp.o -c /vector/src/vector.cpp

Comment: `0` is an `int`, you need a pointer like `nullptr`. At least that is what your error message says. I cannot reproduce it, the only warning is the depreceated `auto_ptr`: https://godbolt.org/z/E1W9T65fE I get the same error with C++03, then `0` ==> `NULL` fixes it https://godbolt.org/z/KcM11jdTd

Comment: strange. I am using g++ (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5). So I should use a nullptr?

Comment: I tryied. I got the same error. wich compiler are you using? I am using the stanard C99

Comment: @Apollo17 Please post the exact command line you pass to gcc. In particular the C++-Standard you are using.

Comment: I did. added the Cmakelists.txt file and the verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I did a casting to (UNITCallback*) and it worked like a charm.
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include"vector.h"


struct UNITEvent_LoopImpl
    {
    UNITEvent_LoopImpl() :
        stopLoop(false),
        callBacks(1024,(UNITCallback*)0),//(FD_SETSIZE, 0),
        priorities(FD_SETSIZE, UNITEvent_Loop::LOW) {};

      //CMSPMutex protect;
      bool      stopLoop;
      std::vector<UNITCallback * > callBacks;
      std::vector<UNITEvent_Loop::priority> priorities;
    };

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```